# jq transform JSON child array objects to delimited string

Tags: json, jq

I want to transform the following input with jq:

```
{
   "root":[
      {
         "field1":"field1value1",
         "field2":"field2value2",
         "field3Array":[
            {
               "prop1":"prop1_value1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "field1":"field1value3",
         "field2":"field2value4",
         "field3Array":[
            {
               "prop1":"prop1_value3"
            },
            {
               "prop1":"prop1_value4"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Output should be:

```
[
  {
    "field1": "field1value1",
    "field2": "field2value2",
    "field3Array": "prop1_value1"
  },
  {
    "field1": "field1value3",
    "field2": "field2value4",
    "field3Array": "prop1_value3,prop1_value4"
  }
]
```

I use this jq filter so far:

```
[.root[] | {field1, field2, field3Array: .field3Array[].prop1}]
```

but I don't know how to join the array property `"prop1"` to a comma-delimited string `"prop1_value3,prop1_value4"`.

https://jqplay.org/s/CR8mGBX8Dz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the objects contained in the `field3Array` to their string values and join the resulting array :

```
.root | map({field1, field2, field3Array: .field3Array | map(.prop1) | join(",")})
```

You can try it [here](https://jqplay.org/s/IlBiXAcAud).

---

It can be somewhat simplified in the following where we update the `.field3Array` in-place instead of recreating a whole object :

```
.root | map(.field3Array |= (map(.prop1) | join(",")))
```

You can try it [here](https://jqplay.org/s/wFwB_10_8C).

---

If you're unfamiliar with the `map` function, the following would have worked as well :

```
[.root[] | {field1, field2, field3Array: [ .field3Array[] | .prop1 ] | join(",")}]
```

You can try it [here](https://jqplay.org/s/wTPAhzvUxG).